# Scifi novel where aliens replicate humans from a signal from Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to identify a novel that I read several years ago and cannot recall the author or title. I recall that the book is the first of two novels.

The plot was this:

Plant-like aliens receive a signal from Earth that includes our genetic code. The aliens use that information to make humans on their planet. One human whose name I cannot recall (the main character) wants to go back to Earth but due to Earth being so far away he would never survive the flight. So the challenge is that he must find a way to do so.

Comment: Are there mind-sucking spiders?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [The Genesis Quest by Donald Moffitt (1986)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Genesis_Quest).

> An alien race (The Nar) assemble humans from a stream of genetic information transmitted by radio from the Milky Way Galaxy.
>
> The resulting colony of humans spend some time integrated into the Nar society before growing restless, discovering the secret of human longevity, and embarking on the seemingly impossible millennia-long mission of a physical journey back to Earth.
>
> This epic journey is made in a gigantic space-grown semi-sentient Dyson tree known as Yggdrasil

Update:
It seems I answered a similar question in 2018!!!
[Story ID. Starfish Aliens recreate humans and then humans become immortal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185050/story-id-starfish-aliens-recreate-humans-and-then-humans-become-immortal/185056?r=SearchResults#185056)

Comment: that's the one I came in to post.  Great book and sequel.